# Posicão de Array em Swift

Tags: array, swift

Gostaria de saber como encontrar a posição de um Array em SWIFT

Alguém sabe?

```
var nomes = ["Douglas", "Marilia", "Roberto", "Carol", "Lucas", "Iasmim", "João", "Zeca"]
nomes.append("Franklyn")
print(nomes)
for constante in nomes{
  print("Constante \(constante)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar

```
if let i = nomes.index(of: "Marilia") {
//Faça o que quiser aqui
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira...

```
let arr:Array = ["Banana","Maça","Laranja"]
find(arr, "Laranja")! // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

A resposta da Andreza está correta, mas caso você precise saber a posição de um elemento dentro de um loop você precisa usar o método `enumerated` no seu array.

```
var nomes = ["Douglas", "Marilia", "Roberto", "Carol", "Lucas", "Iasmim", "João", "Zeca"]
nomes.append("Franklyn")
print(nomes)
for (index, constante) in nomes.enumerated() {
    print("Constante \(constante) at posição \(index)")
}
```

---

Constante Douglas at posição 0

Constante Marilia at posição 1

Constante Roberto at posição 2

Constante Carol at posição 3

Constante Lucas at posição 4

Constante Iasmim at posição 5

Constante João at posição 6

Constante Zeca at posição 7

Constante Franklyn at posição 8